# How do I create a Google Spreadsheet by clicking a button in my Android app?

Tags: android

**I'm creating an app in which I need to create a new Google spreadsheet every time I click a button.** I know how to implement an onClick listener, but I have no clue how to incorporate Google spreadsheets into it. I tried watching a few YouTube tutorials, but they didn't quite have what I was looking for.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you not find: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you mean?  Are you trying to create one via API, or open the Sheets app to a blank spreadsheet that a user could edit?